Maximum number of edges in a graph on 20 vertices with no triangles
I need to find Maximum number of edges in a graph on 20 vertices with no triangles.
We can conclude that $\omega(G) = 2$. Then I've tried to solve the task using chromatic number bounds. We know that $\chi(G) \ge \omega(G) = 2$ and we know $\chi(G)\ge\frac{|V|}{\alpha(G)}$
But it is difficult to say something about $\alpha(G)$...

https://oeis.org/A002620

@RobPratt, thanks! But I really need to understand the idea and intuition of the solution, not just answer

Suppose your graph has maximum degree $k$. Choose a vertex $x$ with $\deg x=k$. Now each of the $k$ neighbors of $x$ has degree $\le20-k$ (since $G$ has no triangles) and each of the $20-k$ non-neighbors of $x$ has degree $\le k$ (since $k$ is the maximum degree. So the sum of the degrees of all the vertices is at most $k(20-k)+(20-k)k=2k(20-k)$, and the numer of edges is half the degree-sum or at most $k(20-k)$.
Now find a value of $k$ that maximizes the quantity $k(20-k)$; this will give you an upper bound for the possible number of edges. Finally, try to find a triangle-free graph that attains that upper bound.
